# PHP File Path With Include

Tags: php, include-path

This is how my project is currently set up:

```
-index.php
-css
--index.css
-includes
--head.php
```

**head.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
<title> My Website </title>
</head>
<body>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include(__DIR__.'/includes/head.php');
?>
```

The problem is that index.css does not work. I don't see what I'm doing wrong at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Note that, `href` is relative to the current browser url path, while the php's `include` is relative to the server path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the way PHP **[`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)** works; it literally **includes** the code from `head.php` into `index.php`, **without** updating any relative links. As such, you `index.php` is looking for the CSS file in `../css/index.css`. And while your `head.php` does indeed need to go up one directory before looking in the CSS folder, your `index.php` file does not.

To resolve this, you have a number of options:

- You can update the relative path to `css/index.css` to work from your `index.php` file.
- You can use the root-relative path `/css/index.css` to reference the CSS file from **any** folder.
- You can use the absolute path `https://yourwebsite.com/css/index.css` to reference the CSS file from not only your website, but any other website. This further eliminates confusion, but will cause issues if you change the domain.

Personally I would recommend the root-relative path, as it makes things less confusing when using things like includes and partials.

Comment: The root-relative path did not work but the relative path did. Thanks!!

Comment: Root-relative links depend on what is considered to be the root of your website. Usually it's the core website itself, though it can be modified through the [**`<base>`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) tag. I'm glad that at least the relative path worked for you though :)